Why does the method worldposition in SCNKit not consider the pivot of the parent's node?
I would like to get the position of a SCNNode (green color) in world coordinates. The SCNNode's parent has a pivot applied to it.
When I use the method worldPosition and place a new blue object with the same world position into the scene then the blue and the green object's positions do not visually match.
Does worldposition not work if a parent has a pivot applied to it?
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
planeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, -0.2, -2)
planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
planeNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0.2, 0)

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

let ballNode = createBallNode(radius: 0.1, color: .green)
planeNode.addChildNode(ballNode)

let debugCube = SCNBox(width: 0.04, height: 0.02, length: 0.7, chamferRadius: 0)
debugCube.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
let debugNode = SCNNode(geometry: debugCube)

let ballWorldPosition = ballNode.worldPosition
debugNode.worldPosition = ballWorldPosition

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(debugNode)
print("Ball World Position: \(ballWorldPosition)")
print("Debug Node Position: \(debugNode.position)")


The output is
Ball World Position: SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -4.0, z: -2.0)
Debug Node Position: SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -4.0, z: -2.0)

I have tried both of these methods without success
let ballWorldPosition = ballNode.worldPosition
let ballWorldPosition = ballNode.convertPosition(ballNode.position, to: nil) 


The test project with the code above can be downloaded here
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ufne6qfz4kqayafs4x8dj/testARKit3.zip?rlkey=p4a9bqwpihin3docbdpuwpys4&dl=0
